# Is struct with class property a thread safe?

Tags: struct, swift4

As far as I know `structs` are thread safe. But when it has a `class` property would it still be a thread safe?

```
struct UserLocation {
    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
}
```

I asked this because I'm currently debugging a random crashes which points to our struct object. Our struct object is being passed in multiple thread.

Due to the ownership of the code I can't post the exact code here so I created a small snippet of the code.

Comment: well no matter what inside the struct, its value driven that what makes it thread safe, therefore a class instance inside it is totally fine because you are passing a new value of it, however i am not 100% sure i would suggest to make property as (  lazy var )

Comment: @Tobi how can I accept your comment as answer? I think you explained it well.

Comment: I could add it as a answer

Comment: @Tobi yeah please add it thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on OP Request, he will accept this comment as answer.

> well no matter what inside the struct, its value driven that what makes it thread safe, therefore a class instance inside it is totally fine because you are passing a new value of it, however i am not 100% sure i would suggest to make property as ( lazy var )